# Why are references successfully produced without a bibliography file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio, overleaf

I'm interested in a paper published in IEEE TPAMI: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.13751, which is open source: https://arxiv.org/e-print/2008.13751 (it seems that this is a `.tar.gz` file).

I downloaded its source files, opened with TeXstudio on Windows, and clicked the `build&view` button:
[image]

Apparently, I can see that the paper is successfully compiled with its references, but I found that it doesn't with `.bib` or some formats of bibliography files.

To obtain a better understanding of its working principles, I was struggling in finding the bibliography items but failed. When I packed this source code into a `.zip` file and import it into [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com), the compilation result is with **no references** (so, why?).

---

**My Problem:**

I'm now so confused about this and don't know how to find out its bibliography file to have a look at the source of its **complete reference list**.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Archive does not support bibtex, so they require authors to include the generated .bbl file. Or perhaps the auhor renamed it. BTW: you are aware that ones does not need a `.bib` file to generated a bibliography?

Comment: I think you've give me the answer. I found the references in its `.bbl` file. @daleif

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I don't think arXiv supports compiling `bibtex` or especially `biblatex` as the latter is very version dependent.

Instead arXiv require that the generated `.bbl` file is uploaded a long with the `.tex` file (or that one directly include the contents of the `.bbl` file into the article.

Thus the reason why it can run without a `.bib` file is that either (1) the `.bbl` already exists and no `bibtex` run is needed, og (2) a manual `thebibliography` is included in the source code.